# Why forward method of torch.autograd.Function has to be static

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, static-methods

I got warnings that

```
/tmp/pip-req-build-58y_cjjl/torch/csrc/autograd/python_function.cpp:638: UserWarning: Legacy autograd function with non-static forward method is deprecated and will be removed in 1.3.
 Please use new-style autograd function with static forward method. (Example: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function)
/tmp/pip-req-build-58y_cjjl/torch/csrc/autograd/python_function.cpp:664: UserWarning: Legacy autograd function object was called twice.  You will probably get incorrect gradients from
 this computation, as the saved tensors from the second invocation will clobber the saved tensors from the first invocation.  Please consider rewriting your autograd function in the m
odern style; for information on the new format, please see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html#extending-torch-autograd
```

which means I must define static forward function in pytorch 1.3 or later version.
I just wonder why forward method of autograd.Function must be static?

Comment: I assume that [this discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-autograd-function-must-it-be-static/14980) should be helpful for you.